# react-select-multi selection ,select props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my muti selection component

```
import React from 'react';
import MultiSelect from "@khanacademy/react-multi-select";

const options = [
  {label: "One", value: 1},
  {label: "Two", value: 2},
  {label: "Three", value: 3},
];

class Consumer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: [],
  }

  render() {
    const {selected} = this.state;

    return <MultiSelect
      options={options}
      selected={selected}
      onSelectedChanged={selected => this.setState({selected})}
    />
  }
}
```

when i click the value, it will be selected in post component, In my view component, I want to show ,how may option I selected using multi selection plugins

Comment: Very bad explenation what you want.. Please update your question.

Comment: please help, you have any Idea, If you want to require more explanation, I will give, please help me, If you know the solution.

Comment: You are wrapping your `Consumer` -component inside `Post` -component and `Post's` want to know how many items is a selected inside `Consumer`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Select
isMulti
/>
```

this `isMulti` will handle multi-select
the `Select` component takes several params. You can make it `Creatable` and as well as `Searchable`. you can refer here https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Comment: when I render component, fetch option checked automatic fire. and display in select box.